# getting error undefined 176 while trying to access API for covid data

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I tried `JSON.parse(data)` but I get:

> *"error undefined at Lat : 54"*.

This is the value from my string. I tried `stringify`, `toString` but I am getting hexadecimal, binary but no data.

Here is my code which I am running:

```
         const express = require("express");
            const https = require("https");
            const app = express();

            const url = "https://api.covid19api.com/live/country/india/status/confirmed";

            app.get("/", function(req, res) {

              https.get(url, function(response) {
                console.log(response.statusCode)
                response.on("data", function(data) {
                  const strCovid = JSON.parse(data);
                  const cases = (strCovid.Confirmed);
                  console.log(cases);
                  res.send("hi" + cases);
                });
              });

            });

            app.listen(3000, function() {
              console.log("server at 3000")
            });
```

Comment: Is the status code returned 200? And have you tried to console.log(data)? If so what's the result

Comment: Please try to post the error as text and not as picture.

Comment: yes i get status code 200, in console.log(data) i get hexadecimal figures. the problem is when i try to convert hexadecimal using parse. then i get this error 
undefined:176
    "Lat": "20.5